# Insert 'n' nodes in a linked list and print their data (C++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I don't understand what's wrong with my code here:

```
//Inserting n nodes, then print their values 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Defining a node and it's head pointer
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
node *head=NULL;
node *link;
node *tmp;


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    while (n>0)
    {   
        //Insert n nodes into the list
        link=new node;
        if (head==NULL)
        {
            head=link;
        }
        cin>>link->data;
        link=link->next;
        n--;
    }
    link=NULL;

    //print data present in those n nodes
    tmp=head;
    while (tmp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<tmp->data;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first part of the code defines a node.

The second part (beginning of main function) is code for creating a linked list with n nodes in it. So I insert n nodes.

Finally, I output them using the pointer tmp. However, instead of getting the data values, I just get an infinite loop. What is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: `link=link->next;` you may want to consider the uselessness of that assignment come the next time you navigate your loop body.

Comment: there are many problems with your code, such as e.g. a memory leak since you're not deleting the memory allocated with `new`, non meaningful code such as `link=link->next` etc. Then again I think you're trying to reinvent the wheel here.. Why not use a std::list<int> instead?

Comment: Why use a linked list at all? Homework. In real life unless you're doing a lot of insert-delete (and I mean inserting and deleting much more often that reading), you are paying a big penalty for that O(1) insert-delete. They have their uses, but they are no where near as useful as the amount of focus you see placed on them in school.

Comment: It wasn't an assignment, I was trying to do linked lists on hackerrank.com. @juanchopanza You should learn to write more useful comments or not write at all.

Comment: I think my comment is quite useful. If you don't learn to code, you'll never get beyond asking people to do your work for you. But of course, you're free to disregard suggestions.

Comment: BTW, you can flag comments as "not constructive" among other things, so it you don't like mine or others, you can do that and then someone else can decide to remove them. I think the threshold for removal is quite low.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're pretty clueless aren't you? But thanks for the suggestion. I flagged your comment a while ago.

Comment: I'm not the one who can't debug their own code.

Comment: @juanchopanza Will let you know when i start caring about your self proclaimed debugging prowess. k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Defining a node and it's head pointer
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next=NULL;
};
node *head=NULL;
node *link;
node *tmp;


int main()
{
    int n,limit;
    cin>>n;
limit=n;

    while (n>0)
    {   
tmp=link;
       link=new node;

     link->next=NULL;
        cin>>link->data;
if (head==NULL)
        {
            head=link;
        }
if(n!=limit)                                                                //check whether tmp is null initially tmp will be null for first element
{
tmp->next=link;
}
        n--;
    }

    //print data present in those n nodes
    tmp=head;
    while (tmp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<tmp->data<<"\n";
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is c++. I recommend to use `std::list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list> // list

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::list<int> l;
    while ( l.size() < n )
    { 
        int data;
        std::cin >> data;
        l.push_back( data );
    }

    for ( int data : l )
        std::cout << data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But if you want to di it yourself you have to remember the tail of your list and add each new node as successor of the tail node. Further you should `delete` the list at the end of your program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
node *head = NULL;

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    node *tail = NULL;
    while ( n>0 )
    {   
        node *link = new node;
        link->next = NULL; // successor of new node is NULL
        std::cin >> link->data;

        if ( head==NULL)
            head = link;       // if list is empty new node is head of list
        else
            tail->next = link; // successor of tail is new node
        tail = link;
        n--;
    }

    node *tmp = head;
    while ( tmp != NULL) // delete the list from head to tail
    {
        std::cout << tmp->data  << std::endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    while ( head != NULL)
    {
       tmp = head->next;
       delete head;
       head = tmp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want using `std::list`. I don't see why you should go on create your own crude and unsafe linked list. (I don't even see why you should use a linked list; in this particular a `std::vector` would be a more reasonable choice).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {

  std::list<int> linked_list;

  // fill the list
  std::cout << "Please enter the number of elements in the list: " << std::endl;
  int n {};
  std::cin>>n;
  while (n-- > 0) { 
    std::cout << "Please enter the data for this item: " << std::endl;
    int data {};
    std::cin>>data;
    linked_list.push_back(data);
  }

  // print out data the list

  for (auto& data : linked_list) 
    std::cout << "printing data entry: " << data << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```